# Mikrotik rb2011uias-2hnd-in experiences WiFi loss until wlan interface is restarted

Tags: wireless-networking, mikrotik-routeros

Driven by recently discovered WPA2 security hole (key reinstallation attack) I updated RouterOS in RB2011uias-2hnd-in from v6.39 to v6.40.5.

It didn't improve connection quality, but now I'm experiencing from time to time a complete WiFi loss which could be resolved either by WLAN interface disable/enable or by complete router reboot. WLAN can work for several days or may disappear in few minutes after restart.

Do you experience this too? Did you fix it? How?

**Update**

Yesterday I updated RouterOS and firmware to v 6.41.2 and now WiFi is always there ... just the access to network disappears with same frequency as WiFi used to disappear. In the recent version they did something to RouterOS bridges, but WLAN restart helps for a while.

Comment: What WPA2 Security hole are you referring to? You could probably roll back the firmware and see if this is software or hardware related. just a guess but this sounds like it may be a firmware caveat.

Comment: https://www.krackattacks.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, microtik routers running 6.39.3 and up are unaffected by the KrackAttack security hole.(unless running in WDS WiFi/nstream modes).
https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=126695

The problems you are experiencing with this version are being shared by other users. Make your voice heard, they are asking for anyone with bugs or issues with this release to report them to microtik. You are perfectly safe to roll-back to v6.39 as it is not vunerable to the attack.
https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=127485

I'm not sure how that version made it past QA. But deffinately report your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Tim. When rolling back to v6.39 should I downgrade firmware too?

Comment: I would match it exactly to the setup you had when you were not experiencing drop-outs. Keep your eye on the releases, upgrade when they work out the bugs. It seems like they are doing a major overhaul of the router OS in the new versions.

Comment: You are very welcome Paul!